# WebRTC source download fails

Tags: ios, macos, webrtc

When trying to download WebRTC latest source for iOS on Mac, its failing with the following error:

```
Running: gclient sync --with_branch_heads
Error: Command '/usr/bin/python src/webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc -Dextra_gyp_flag=0' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /Users/Latest
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Latest/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 346, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/Users/Latest/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 341, in main
return run(options, spec, root)
File "/Users/Latest/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 335, in run
return checkout.init()
File "/Users/Latest/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 142, in init
self.run_gclient(*sync_cmd)
File "/Users/Latest/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 76, in run_gclient
return self.run(cmd_prefix + cmd, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Latest/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 66, in run
return subprocess.check_output(cmd, **kwargs)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('gclient', 'sync', '--with_branch_heads')' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

I'm following the same steps given [here](https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/)
Any solution?

Comment: I can confirm the identical problem.  On Ubuntu 14.04 system I have and another in a different city running Ubuntu 12.04 - not sure if Google has a server problem or what.

Answer (score 0):

do you install depot tools?

> [(1) Prerequisite Software](https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/prerequisite-sw/)
>
> [(2) install-depot-tools](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/install-depot-tools)

Comment: Yes, I installed depot tools